# WAMP + Pear installation issue

Tags: pear, wamp

I am trying to install PEAR in my WAMP-server. The `go-pear.bat` is running as intended, but when it comes to changing the directories, it all goes wrong.
I have followed this guide: http://phphints.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/installing-pear-package-manager-on-wamp/

The 9th line of configuration, Public Web Files directory, will not change upon command and instead says `Input file error, no file extension in C:\documents`

I am running XP SP3. Is there anyone else who had experienced this slight issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes up to the same problem, try to rewrite all lines of configuration! It worked finally for me

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on My Computer -> Properties, Advanced tab, Environment Variables. For the environment variables TEMP and TMP values take double quotes. For example, for TEMP was `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp`, but must be `"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp"`

Comment: Hi Garik, sorry, but I cannot understand your answer. If you wish to translate it to english, it would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a literal Google translation of above answer:

Right-click on My Computer -> Properties, Advanced tab, Environment Variables. For the environment variables TEMP and TMP values ​​take in double quotes. For example, for TEMP was% USERPROFILE% \ Local Settings \ Temp, but must "% USERPROFILE% \ Local Settings \ Temp"

Answer (score 0):

Since my go-pear.phar was signed I was unable to edit the installation script. What DID work for me and was easier than editing system Envionment Variables through the XP interface, was to simply create `c:\temp` and then in the same cmd box you're in to run go-pear, type `set temp=c:\temp` and `set tmp=c:\temp` and you're good to go to run go-pear. Note that setting the `Temp` and `Tmp` manually here in the cmd box mean that they will only last for that session. After installation you can delete `c:\temp`